# joomla menu access - good on user not on viewer

Tags: php, joomla

hello guy's i have a problem in this menu in joomla php code
i want both viewer and user can access the currency button.
there no problem in login user

```
<?php
/**
 * @version     1.0.4
 * @package     Joomla
 * @subpackage  EShop
 * @author      Giang Dinh Truong
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2011 Ossolution Team
 * @license     GNU/GPL, see LICENSE.php
*/
// no direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php JURI::base(); ?>index.php?option=com_eshop&task=currency.change">
<div id="currency" class="eshop-currency<?php echo $params->get( 'moduleclass_sfx' ); ?>">
    <?php
    for ($i = 0; $n = count($currencies), $i < $n; $i++)
    {
        $currency = $currencies[$i];
        if ($currency->currency_code == $currencyCode)
        {
            ?>
            <a title="<?php echo $currency->currency_name; ?>">
                <b><?php echo $currency->currency_code; ?></b>
            </a>
            <?php
        }
        else 
        {
            ?>
            <a onclick="jQuery('input[name=\'currency_code\']').attr('value', '<?php echo $currency->currency_code; ?>'); jQuery(this).parent().parent().submit();" title="<?php echo $currency->currency_name; ?>">
                <?php echo $currency->currency_code; ?>
            </a>
            <?php
        }
    }
    ?>
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="currency_code" />
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo base64_encode(JURI::getInstance()->toString()); ?>" name="return" />
</div>
```

here the link www.skitty.com.ph
try to change php to dollar currency

Comment: Please elaborate, and also mention how is this related to Joomla?

Comment: the problem is that i can't change the currency button from dollar to php vice versa when i am not login although the menu from the user and the viewer has the same menu

Comment: You're using `com_eshop` which is a 3rd party extension, so I'd recommend contacting the developer